# How do I program buttons to de/select all rows & columns in a table?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jbutton, actionevent

This is my code. I use a controller in order to have everything more clean.

```
public class ControladorModificarMiembros implements IControladorModificarMiembros{

private VentanaModificarMiembros ventana;

private List<MiembroEnGrupo> miembros = new ArrayList<>();
        
ControladorModificarMiembros()
{
    this.ventana = new VentanaModificarMiembros(this,null);  //Instancia la ventana
    this.ventana.setLocationRelativeTo(null);       //Centra la ventana
    this.ventana.getTablaMiembros().setModel(new ModeloTablaMiembros());     //Asignamos modelo a la tabla       
    
    
    ModeloTablaMiembros mta = (ModeloTablaMiembros) this.ventana.getTablaMiembros().getModel();
    
    IGestorAutores ga = GestorAutores.crear();
    List<MiembroEnGrupo> miembrosengrupo = new ArrayList<>();
    
    for(Autor g : ga.verAutores())
    {
        MiembroEnGrupo e = new MiembroEnGrupo(g,null);    
        miembrosengrupo.add(e);
    }
    
    mta.asignarMiembrosEnGrupo(miembrosengrupo);
    
    JComboBox comboRoles = new JComboBox();
    comboRoles.setModel(new ModeloComboRol());
    
    TableColumn tmpColumn = this.ventana.getTablaMiembros().getColumnModel().getColumn(1);
    tmpColumn.setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(comboRoles));
    
    this.ventana.setVisible(true); //Makes it visible
}

@Override
public void btnTodosClic(ActionEvent evt) {
    ModeloTablaAutores mta = (ModeloTablaAutores) this.ventana.getTablaMiembros().getModel();
    mta.actualizar();
```

//HERE IS WHERE I HAVE TO PROGRAM THE JBUTTON IN ORDER TO PRESS IT AND AUTOMATICALLY SELECT ALL THE TABLE

```
@Override
public void btnNingunoClic(ActionEvent evt) {

    ModeloTablaAutores mtg = (ModeloTablaAutores) this.ventana.getTablaMiembros().getModel();
```

//HERE IS WHERE I HAVE TO PROGRAM THE JBUTTON THAT WILL ALLOW TO DESELECT THE ROW THAT IS ALREADY SELECTED

Comment: I added an example in an answer.

Answer (score 2):

`JTable` provides this functionality for free. With [`selectAll()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#selectAll()) and [`clearSelection`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#clearSelection()).

All you need to do is, to call these methods on your table in the corresponding `actionListener` of your buttons.

Demo snippet:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
        buildGui();
    });
}

private static void buildGui() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    String[] header = { "Data1", "Data2" };
    Object[][] data = new Object[][] { { "Entry1", "Entry2" }, { "Entry3", "Entry4" } };
    JTable table = new JTable(data, header);
    JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(table);
    
    JButton btnSelect = new JButton("Select All");
    // on button click of "SelectAll"
    btnSelect.addActionListener((event) -> table.selectAll());
    JButton btnUnselect = new JButton("Unselect All");
    // on button click of "Unselect All"
    btnUnselect.addActionListener((event) -> table.clearSelection());
    
    JPanel btnPanel = new JPanel();
    btnPanel.add(btnSelect);
    btnPanel.add(btnUnselect);
    
    frame.add(sp);
    frame.add(btnPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

1. Nothing selected:

[image: unselected]

2. "SelectAll" pressed:

[image: selectall]

After pressing "Unselect All", it is back to 1.